# How to show that an algorithm is not fair?

Tags: machine-learning

Algorithm fairness is the field of research aimed at understanding and correcting biases like these. It is at the intersection of machine learning and ethics. Specifically, the field includes: Researching the causes of bias in data and algorithms.

There are several ways to define fairness. I am interested in the individual fairness (see in the figure below).At an individual level, fairness can be defined as similar individuals being treated similarly. At a group level, a fair outcome demands the existence of parity between different protected groups, such as those defined by gender or race.

[image]

I am currently working on similarity of multimedia objects. I want to measure the  individual fairness of the algorithm $A$ I am using on a dataset $D$. How to show that algorithm $A$ is fair or not on the dataset $D$?

Comment: Without more specific description of the kind of processing you have in mind, this question is meaningless. As a rule, in computer algorithms all data items are treated the same way. Maybe your concern is related to the theory of sampling, which is not a computer science discipline.

Comment: To give you more description of the algorithm, algorithm takes two multimedia objects and compute their hash (based upon the features), if the hash value is same then multimedia objects are same else not. Here bias might come from the ways data is stored. I am not interested in the bias coming from the traning.

Comment: A hash is used to store and retrieve the data quickly; in case of collisions, the original data is used to resolve it. No bias is possible. By the way, a hash is meant to scramble the data in a quasi-random way and uniformizes the distribution.

Comment: Just to clarify the answer a bit: $D(O(I_i), O(I_j)) \le d(I_i, I_j)$ is violated by (all?) functions which we call hashes.

Comment: True, but how to show?

Comment: What sources are you reading?  Please credit the source of all images and copied material.  Please make your question self-contained by defining all notation.  I don't know what the variables $I_i,I_j,O,D,\dots$ represent.  Does your source give a precise definition of fairness?  Have you tried applying the definition?

Answer (score 0):

Hash codes are computed using the same formula on all keys and are designed to yield dissimilar values even from similar data. The semantic interpretation of the data is irrelevant and will be "erased" by hashing. No unfairness is possible.

In addition, hash codes are used in hash tables, that have collision arbitration mechanisms, so that all data are stored and none is lost. Speaking of unfairness would be perfectly irrelevant.